# Entry XML tag is causing the XSL value-of to not work

Tags: xml, xslt, value-of

I have a (simplified) XML file I'm trying to transform:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.symplectic.co.uk/vivo/" xmlns:api="http://www.symplectic.co.uk/publications/api">
<tag>Hello, Hello.</tag>
</entry>
```

Wrapping my content in the "entry" tag seems to cause problems with this statement in my XSLT.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$xmlfile/entry/tag"/>
```

Where the $xmlFile is the fn:document output of the above XML. I have found that when removing the entry tags from the XML and simply modifying my XSLT to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$xmlfile/tag"/>
```

I get the content (Hello,Hello) I'm expecting in my output. I have verified that doing a copy-of $xmlfile returns the full XML file. I'm sure there is something I'm not doing right syntactically as I'm new to XSL. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you remove the "xmlns" attribute on "entry", does it work?

Comment: Hi, you should be able to use the root `entry` element in your xpath lookup (see here for an example - http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#d5e25672). Two questions. 1) How is the `$xmlfile` variable defined? 2) Why aren't you using the namespace in your xpath? (Can you please provide the full xsl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is indeed with the **entry** element...

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.symplectic.co.uk/vivo/"
```

The **xmlns** attribute here is actually a namespace declaration. Or rather, because it does declare a prefix (like **xmlns:api** does) it is the default namespace. This means the **entry** element and its child **tag** element belong to the namespace.

Now, your xslt is doing this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="$xmlfile/entry/tag"/>
```

This is looking for **entry** and **tag** elements that belong to NO namespace. These are different to elements with the same name that do belong to a namespace.

The solution is to declare the namespace, with a prefix, in the XSLT, like so

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:vivo="http://www.symplectic.co.uk/vivo/">
```

Then change your xslt expression to look like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$xmlfile/vivo:entry/vivo:tag"/>
```

Note the actual prefix is no important, but the namespace url must match.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This worked perfectly, and I understand a little bit more about XSLT now. :)

Answer (score 0):

XPath and XSLT are namespace-aware. To specify a namespaced node in a path, you should give the node name a prefix that you have bound to the correct namespace.

Using wildcards, and then adding a predicate to test only the localname, is possible but generally the Wrong Answer. Namespaces are a meaningful part of the name. Use them properly.